# Bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet

How can I spot,find my bitcoin wallet?I have a bitcoin address and I collect btcs daily but I can't recall the website which is the source of my wallet and account.What can I do?

Comment: If this is a serious question, then post more details if you can. When you created the wallet might help. Was it a wallet service that is completely online? Maybe coinbase.com ?

Comment: This question's title is meaningless, it should be improved.

Answer (score 3):

You really only have two options:

1. Try and remember the website you used (maybe you have an email from it?)
2. If you have a wallet backup, send the coins to a new address/wallet